# $0$-Attractiveness implies stability $y'(t)=Ay(t), A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let A be such that the zero solution of $y'(t)=Ay(t), A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is attractive. Show the zero solution is also stable.

Looking at the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definitions of attractiveness and stability, I can't see how attractiveness is enough to show that solutions are close together for **all** $t$, not just in the limit.

To further complicate matters, we have only ever worked with reals, so I'm not sure what results from class may be used in this complex case.

Is there some other way than the use of the definitions to approach this problem? If the definitions are the way to go, how do I argue for small $t$?

My only idea is to somehow use the fact that $A$ is linear, but then again that doesn't necessarily mean the functions are linear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This being a linear homogeneous DE, the solutions are linear combinations of
$n$ basic solutions $y_j$, say with $y_j(0) = e_j$ the $j$'th standard unit vectors.
Note that if $y_j(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, $y_j$ is bounded.  If all $|y_j(t)| < B$, and $|y(0)| < \delta$, can you bound $|y(t)|$?

Comment: Future readers: the exponential function is continuous so $\exp(tA)$ is continuous in $t$, implying all $y_j$ are continuous.